# appium + Handle facebook webview for verifying social login

Tags: selenium, webview, appium

I have to verify social login which is opened webview in android application.

On clicking the button for facebook social login, facebook is opened in `webview` and it do not allow to enter username or password.

How can I handle this ?

I tried below code but it prints NATIVE_APP only.

```
 private void setUpWebView() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
            for (Object contextName :  contextNames) {
                System.out.println(contextName);
                if (contextName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("WEBVIEW")){
                    driver.context(contextName.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: WebView]

Comment: have you switched your context to webview?

Comment: After switching context how can I enter user name and password ?

Comment: you can use sendkeys to enter text

Comment: I have updated the code. I used it but it does not help.

Comment: so how you become sure that your app is opened in webview context? i think if ypur element locator is ok, than you can type text using sendkeys easily. give the appium error log after using the sendkeys function

Comment: I will attach the screenshot from uiautomatorviewer

Comment: so how you locate your element to click, from your pic, the xpath or name is not clear for email address text filed.

Comment: That is what I want to know. In this case how to handle such scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122174/discussion-between-noor-and-abhinav).

Comment: I am able to click on OK button of webview of facebook using xpath with no problem, have you tried xpath? if senkeys dont work, try click the field before and then sendkeys